# Javascript code not working on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I'm using a Javascript code to hide/show some divs based on a click of some other divs, although the code works perfectly on PC browsers, can't work in iOS devices (iPad/iPhone), worth clarifying that it work perfectly on macOS (iMac/Macbook). I'm using Elementor and Wordpress but I don't think this has anything to do with it.

```
// Check if the body doesn't have the CSS class 'elementor-editor-active'
if (!document.body.classList.contains('elementor-editor-active')) {
    const catButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.packages-btn, .programs-btn, .workshops-btn, .courses-btn, .tools-btn');
    const catContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.packages-container, .programs-container, .workshops-container, .courses-container, .tools-container');
  
    // If packages-btn clicked
    function packagesBtnClick() {
      for (let i = 0; i < catContainers.length; i++) {
        if (!catContainers[i].classList.contains('packages-container')) {
          catContainers[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
      document.querySelector('.packages-container').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('.btns-container').style.setProperty('--color-overlay-feria-container', '#009BB7');
    }
  
    catButtons.forEach((elemento) => {
      if (elemento.classList.contains('packages-btn')) {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', packagesBtnClick);
      }
    });
  
    // If programs-btn clicked
    function programsBtnClick() {
      for (let i = 0; i < catContainers.length; i++) {
        if (!catContainers[i].classList.contains('programs-container')) {
          catContainers[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
      document.querySelector('.programs-container').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('.btns-container').style.setProperty('--color-overlay-feria-container', '#E27727');
    }
  
    catButtons.forEach((elemento) => {
      if (elemento.classList.contains('programs-btn')) {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', programsBtnClick);
      }
    });
  
    // If workshops-btn clicked
    function workshopsBtnClick() {
      for (let i = 0; i < catContainers.length; i++) {
        if (!catContainers[i].classList.contains('workshops-container')) {
          catContainers[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
      document.querySelector('.workshops-container').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('.btns-container').style.setProperty('--color-overlay-feria-container', '#A9C45C');
    }
  
    catButtons.forEach((elemento) => {
      if (elemento.classList.contains('workshops-btn')) {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', workshopsBtnClick);
      }
    });
  
    // If courses-btn clicked
    function coursesBtnClick() {
      for (let i = 0; i < catContainers.length; i++) {
        if (!catContainers[i].classList.contains('courses-container')) {
          catContainers[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
      document.querySelector('.courses-container').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('.btns-container').style.setProperty('--color-overlay-feria-container', '#FFC23F');
    }
  
    catButtons.forEach((elemento) => {
      if (elemento.classList.contains('courses-btn')) {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', coursesBtnClick);
      }
    });
  
    // If tools-btn clicked
    function toolsBtnClick() {
      for (let i = 0; i < catContainers.length; i++) {
        if (!catContainers[i].classList.contains('tools-container')) {
          catContainers[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
      document.querySelector('.tools-container').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('.btns-container').style.setProperty('--color-overlay-feria-container', '#AD2A27');
    }
  
    catButtons.forEach((elemento) => {
      if (elemento.classList.contains('tools-btn')) {
        elemento.addEventListener('click', toolsBtnClick);
      }
    });
  }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: is it all the `.style.display =` code that "isn't working"?

Comment: Also, do you mind adding some HTML to the question so that we can see what you're dealing with

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, divs that act as buttons are clicked and nothing happen, it could be the .style.display = option is not working, it suppose that on every click of the differents divs that act as buttons, some containers should disappear and the others should appear.